# Android ViewModel, List of items, inserting - handling state

Tags: android, rest, mvvm, retrofit2, viewmodel

My question is kind of not strictly precised. I have a Fragment with list of items that are backed up by REST API service:

```
GET /api/items
```

I have a ItemsViewModel class, ItemsProvider with LiveData objects and APIService that get the items from REST service. The implementation of ListFragment observes the ItemsViewModel and its state.

Now I have a question. How do you implement inserting data into ViewModel in your implementations? How do you handle state update?

Comment: Please share some code, so i can explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can take **`LiveData<List<? of items>>`** as `MutableLiveData` inside `ItemsViewModel`.

Now, when you've new items, you need to set your `LiveData` value.

You need to create an `observer` to that inside of your `activity/fragment` where you needed.